# Stopping CGI Email Script through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

```
    <form name="post" ACTION="http://epansoftware.com/cgi-sys/cgiemail/cgi-bin/cgimailx.txt" accept-charset="UTF-8" METHOD="post">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>OR LEAVE US A MESSAGE HERE</legend>
    <label for="name" class="fixedwidth">Name</label>
    <input type="text" Name="name" id="name" value="" size="50"/><br />
    <label for="company" class="fixedwidth">Company</label>
    <input type="text" Name="company" id="company" value="" size="50"/><br />
    <label for="email" class="fixedwidth">Email</label>
    <input type="text" Name="email" id="email" size="50"/><br />
    <label for="subject" class="fixedwidth">Subject</label>
    <select name="subject" id="subject">
    <option>Support</option>
    <option>Sales Inquiry</option>
    <option>Custom Database</option>
    </select><br />
    <label for="message" class="fixedwidth">Message</label>
    <textarea type="text" Name="message" id="message" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>
    <div class="buttonarea">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="testResults()">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="success" VALUE="http://www.epansoftware.com">
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I have this form in HTML, as well as this javascript function defined in the header:

```
  <script language="javascript">
    function testResults()
    {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var fields = new Array();
    fields[0] = name;
    fields[1] = email;
    fields[2] = message;
    var tester = /[A-z]|[0-9]/;
    if(! tester.test(fields[0]))
    {
      alert("Please type information in all the required fields!");
      return false;
    }
    else if(! tester.test(fields[1]))
    {
      alert("Please type information in all the required fields!");
    }
    else if(! tester.test(fields[2]))
    {
      alert("Please type information in all the required fields!");
    }
    else if(tester.test(fields[0]) && tester.test(fields[1]) && tester.test(fields[2]))
    {
      alert("Your message has been sent!");
    }
    else
    {
      alert("ERROR 5: Regex Error");
    }
  }
</script>
```

My problem is that when I call the function, if all the fields aren't filled out, I don't want an e-mail sent. However, the way it is now, an email will be sent no matter what. Is there any way to stop the CGI script (that's what the action is doing in the form method) from running from the javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Add `return false` to the end of your function. In your `<form>` tag add `onSubmit="return testResults()"` (remove how you are calling it now). The `return false` in the `onSubmit` attribute of the `<form>` tag will prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: Didn't work with `onSubmit="return testResults()"`, but I got it with `onClick="return testResults()"` Thanks